# Awaiting Multiple Tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I have the following pieces of code:

```
private async void buttonStart_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    Bot b = new Bot(_names);
    var result = await b.Start(false, true, false);
    MessageBox.Show("Done");
}

public async Task<bool> Start(bool instagram, bool twitter, bool xbox)
{
    if (twitter)
    {
        Twitter t = new Twitter(Names);
        await t.CheckNames();
    }
    return true;
}

public Task CheckNames()
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (Name name in Names)
    {
        tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            TwitterResponse result = await Check(name);
            MessageBox.Show(result.msg);
        }));
    }
    return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

public async Task<TwitterResponse> Check(Name name)
{
    HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await http.GetAsync(string.Format("https://twitter.com/users/username_available?username={0}", name.Value));
    string html = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    TwitterResponse result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<TwitterResponse>(html);
    return result;
}
```

However, I always seem to get the `MessageBox` saying `"Done"` before any of the tasks are completed.

Am I doing something wrong, how can I make sure all of the tasks actually complete before getting the `messagebox`?

Comment: @LB that duplicate you linked is not the cause, it is his use of Task.Factory.StartNew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the line `tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>`, [you should almost never be using `Task.Factory.StartNew`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) and instead use `Task.Run(`.

The object that `StartNew` is returning is a `Task<Task>` which means it does not wait for the inner task to finish. You must either call `.Unwrap()` on the output of the `StartNew` before you add it to the collection or, much much better use `Task.Run(`

```
tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
{
    TwitterResponse result = await Check(name);
    MessageBox.Show(result.msg);
}));
```

Which has a overload that takes in a `Func<Task>` and will unwrap the inner task for you.

Comment: Is there a way that I can make it run faster? Say maybe 5 or 10 at a time?

Comment: Yes, but that has nothing to do with the problem you are trying to solve. I would ask a new question about that. However before you do I would suggest you look in to [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh228603(v=VS.110).aspx) that is the "modern" way to do parallel workflows while still being able to await the work being done.